# Nivo slider prev and next links not displaying in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, nivo-slider

You can see here: http://tonysandwich.co.uk/rockinghorses that there is a prev and next button on the image slider.

When looking at this in IE8 these buttons cease to exist. The IE inspector doesn't even pick up the div or the content.

Here is the section of the script I am referring to:

```
// Add Direction nav
    if(settings.directionNav){
        slider.append('<div class="nivo-directionNav"><a class="nivo-prevNav"></a><a class="nivo-nextNav"></div>');



        $('a.nivo-prevNav', slider).live('click', function(){
            if(vars.running) { return true; }
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = '';
            vars.currentSlide -= 2;
            nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'prev');
        });

        $('a.nivo-nextNav', slider).live('click', function(){
            if(vars.running) { return true; }
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = '';
            nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'next');
        });
    }
```

Here is the CSS:

```
     /* Direction nav styles (e.g. Next & Prev) */
.nivo-directionNav a {
      cursor:pointer;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: -90px;
      z-index: 100;
}

.nivo-prevNav {
    left:0px;
    width: 61px;
    height: 27px;
    background-image:url(images/Back%202.png);
    top: 105%;
            }

.nivo-nextNav {
    right:0px;
    width: 106px;
    height: 126px;
    background-image:url(images/Next%202.png);
    top: 85%;
    margin-right: -25px;

}
```

I don't know if it's something to do with the fact that the div that the prev and next is located within is in the javascript file and for this reason IE8 can't seem to see it.

If anyone can provide me with an insight as to how I can get this to display in IE8 that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a problem with the Nivo slider in IE8. Google around for that should help!

Comment: Added some code and a bit more information, been looking at the problem most of the day to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have solved it.

I downloaded the previous version of the nivo slider script and took the below code from it and added it to the latest version of the code.

I added it immediately under the code shown above and as if by magic the buttons are now happily displaying in IE8 and I have regained my sanity.

```
$('a.nivo-prevNav', slider).live('click', function(){
            if(vars.running) { return false; }
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = '';
            vars.currentSlide -= 2;
            nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'prev');
        });

        $('a.nivo-nextNav', slider).live('click', function(){
            if(vars.running) { return false; }
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = '';
            nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'next');
        });
```